# cx_freeze can't find oslo module

Tags: python, python-2.7, cx-freeze, oslo

I'm trying to use cx_freeze to create a Windows executable from a Python script that imports pyrax (to interface with Rackspace). Pyrax  requires oslo (https://github.com/openstack/oslo.utils), a module for working with OpenStack that I have installed. When I try to run the compiled .exe, it says that it can't find the module 'oslo.utils'. When I try to include that module, or just the oslo module, in my setup.py file, I get the following error:

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 45, in <module>
    executables = [execu]
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 362, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 232, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 606, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 346, in _GetModuleFinder
    finder.IncludeModule(name)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 678, in IncludeModule
    namespace = namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 386, in _ImportModule
    raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'oslo.utils'
```

I'm on Windows 8 running Python 2.7 via a Continuum Anaconda install. I've installed oslo v1.0.0 using pip (and reinstalled it in an attempt to fix this, but to no avail). Cx_freeze is version 4.3.3, and the oslo module not an egg or zip, but is foldered with everything else under site-packages.

'Import oslo' and 'import oslo.utils' both work in the interpreter. Other modules manually included in setup.py work correctly. My setup.py file looks like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

# include email.__init__ lazy imports manually for pyrax
MIMENAMES = [
    'audio',
    'base',
    'image',
    'message',
    'multipart',
    'nonmultipart',
    'text',
    ]

email_includes = ['email.mime.' + x for x in MIMENAMES]

includes = ['oslo.utils']
includes.extend(email_includes)

include_files = []

execu = Executable(
  script = "main.py",
  initScript = None,
  base = base,
  targetName = "main.exe",
  compress = False,
  copyDependentFiles = True,
  appendScriptToExe = False,
  appendScriptToLibrary = False,
  icon = None
)

setup(  name = "issgmain",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "my description",
        options = {"build_exe": {"includes":includes, "include_files": include_files}},
        executables = [execu]
        )
```

Thoughts and workarounds much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That traceback indicates that something in your setup.py is adding `'oslo.py'` to the `includes` list. The line numbers also indicate that there's more in your setup.py script than you've shown. Includes is a list of module names, not filenames, so you should include 'oslo', without the .py extension.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I unintentionally posted the traceback and the setup script from different runs. The line numbers in the traceback and the 'oslo.py' are from a setup with more comments and the addition of the .py was a desperation try to make something work. Bottom line is that with the setup script posted above I get the same error, only replace 'oslo.py' with 'oslo'. Will update the tracback with the correct one when I get the chance.

Comment: OK. Can you do `import oslo.utils; print(oslo.utils)` to see where it's loaded from in Python?

Comment: Here's the result: <module 'oslo.utils' from 'C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\oslo\utils\__init__.pyc'>. That's the path where everything else is installed as well. Thanks!

Comment: OK, and if you put a `print(sys.path)` into your setup.py file, is `C:\Users\Devin\Anaconda\lib\site-packages` one of the directories it shows in the list?

Comment: It is one of the directories. Strangely, it is there twice, once normally and once printed at the end of sys.path all lowercase. Other than that, no anomalies stand out to me.

Comment: If you add `"packages":["oslo"]` to the build_exe options, does it make any difference? Can you show the full output from freezing (put it in a pastebin)?

Comment: No difference, alas. Pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/NVwhaWbk. Again, thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Ah, wait a minute, oslo is a namespace package. Try with `"namespace_packages":["oslo"]`

Comment: Thank you, sir, that was it. Adding just `"namespace_packages":["oslo"]` made the build hang, but adding `"packages":["oslo"]` as well and it goes through. Much appreciated. Happy to select an answer if you respond that way with this final solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

Add to the build_exe options:

```
"namespace_packages":["oslo"]
```

`oslo` is a namespace package, and cx_Freeze needs to know about it for things to work correctly.

Apparently you also need to add it to packages:

```
"packages":["oslo"]
```

I'm not sure why this step is needed as well.